# PC/Xbox Controller servo control

Tags: pi-zero, pigpio, gamepad

I am making a project where I want to use a PC/Xbox controller to control my servos with analog sticks. I've been following this [tutorial](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-xbox-360-controller-wireless/) and I've used the code down below to control my servo motor with an analog stick, but encountered a problem of servo jitter, while using RPi.GPIO. I wrote a simple program, which controls the servo with the use of PIGPIO library and it works perfectly. Can anybody help me to transform the code below to use a PIGPIO library instead?

Thank you.

Code I'm using with RPi.GPIO:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import math
import xbox

GPIO_SERVO_PIN  = 20

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(GPIO_SERVO_PIN, GPIO.OUT)


def updateServo(pwm, angle):
    duty = float(angle) / 10.0 + 2.5
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)

def angleFromCoords(x,y):
    angle = 0.0
    if x==0.0 and y==0.0:
        angle = 90.0
    elif x>=0.0 and y>=0.0:
        # first quadrant
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x)) if x!=0.0 else 90.0
    elif x<0.0 and y>=0.0:
        # second quadrant
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x))
        angle += 180.0
    elif x<0.0 and y<0.0:
        # third quadrant
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x))
        angle += 180.0
    elif x>=0.0 and y<0.0:
        # third quadrant
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x)) if x!=0.0 else -90.0
        angle += 360.0
    return angle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    joy = xbox.Joystick()
    pwm = GPIO.PWM(GPIO_SERVO_PIN, 100)
    pwm.start(5)

    while not joy.Back():
        # Servo
        x, y = joy.leftStick()
        angle = angleFromCoords(x,y)
        if angle > 180 and angle < 270:
            angle = 180
        elif angle >= 270:
            angle = 0
        updateServo(pwm, angle)

    joy.close()
    pwm.stop()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following for a start.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio
import math
import xbox

GPIO_SERVO_PIN  = 20

MIN_ANG=-180.0 #degrees
MAX_ANG=180.0  #degrees

MIN_PW=1000 # microseconds
MAX_PW=2000 # microseconds

ANG_RANGE=MAX_ANG-MIN_ANG
PW_RANGE=MAX_PW-MIN_PW
PWAR=float(PW_RANGE)/ANG_RANGE

RAD2DEG=180.0/math.pi

def angleToPulseWidth(angle):
   """
   angle is mapped to valid pulse widths for servo
   which are determined by experiment.
   """
   assert MIN_ANG <= angle <= MAX_ANG
   return MIN_PW + ((angle - MIN_ANG) * PWAR)


if __name__ == '__main__':

   import pigpio
   import time

   pi = pigpio.pi()
   if not pi.connected:
      exit()

   joy = xbox.Joystick()

   while not joy.Back():
      x, y = joy.leftStick()
      angle = math.atan2(y, x) * RAD2DEG
      pw = angleToPulseWidth(angle)
      pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(GPIO_SERVO_PIN, pw)
      time.sleep(0.01)

   joy.close()
   pi.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seems to work quite good when I tilt the stick to the left and move it up and down. When it comes to the right side, it kinda slows down and doesn't move so much. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Max.F I can't help there as I don't have a joystick and have little idea of how they operate.